# Would the professor leave the classroom if only 1 student uses their cellphone during class?

Tags: professorship, university

I’m a college student. My class has only 40 students. My professor left the classroom before class ended because, like he said, too many students were using phones while he was talking. It was not like there were phone sounds or the phones rang. He said before leaving that he would let us teach ourselves.

In this case, I’m quite curious about something:

1. Would he be able or be allowed to not teach, and let us handle it ourselves and only come in to do the test?
2. Would he be able to fail the whole class?
3. Would he possibly react the same way if only 1 student used their phone without making any noise?

Comment: It depends on the severity and persistence of the disturbance. Some do not intervene if people use their phones silently. They accept students as adults, who are entitled to decide to spend all their study fees to be able to facebook against a pleasant lecture background noise. After all, they might even look up stuff in the internet (say). With noise, however, it is an entirely different story. However: ...

Comment: ...a prof has the right to determine the pedagogical milestones of his course. He can decide that students do not learn well with mobiles active. Failure rates may hound him, too, so he is entitled to measures to improve studying. Whether this measure (leaving a room) is effective, I won't guess. But I can understand that he considers a situation with too many mobiles on not conducive to education and he should in principle have the choice to react to that in a way that he thinks will bring about a more effective change in students' material uptake.

Comment: I recall first year at university a lecturer walked out when one student threw a paper plane (which hit the board in front of him). Next lecture when he walked in half the students threw planes - looking back both the walk out and the response of students seem a little immature.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth Having a sense of humour as a lecturer can help getting the class on your side (instead of walking out). But having a whole swarm of planes thrown at you - well, someone clearly didn't do a proper job during high school time, and it's probably not just the students.

Comment: Answers could vary wildly.  At the places I have worked, the answers to these questions would be no, but a colleague told me that when he taught in Africa all those things were yes.

Comment: Even if the phone isn't making sound, I find it hard to stay focused on a lecture when there are things moving on a screen at the edge of my field of view. This means that if the person next to me or in front of me in class is on their phone, I might have a harder time concentrating.

Comment: @usernumber While I've never been in classrooms where there are people constantly in my field of view using phones (I always sit at the front when possible) I certainly find this an irritating distraction if I'm in the theatre, even if the lights aren't down. I can easily see how it could cause disruption, regardless of how "quiet" the student using it is.

Comment: I don't blame the professor for reacting to the situation but I think they should have taken a much more constructive reaction such as stopping the lecture mid-sentence to write the names of students which are rudely using their phones. You won't believe how quickly the users catch on and put their phones away.

Comment: Consider the opposite. Lecturer starts lecture, then stops and uses mobile. Somehow I think the students would be affronted. (except perhaps for those *already* using their mobiles, who couldn't have been paying the attention needed anyway...)

Comment: I am surprised it doesn't work the other way. Down here a lecturer could order students to leave class if he considers them disruptive. While majority probably wouldn't do it for just having phone out, talking over phone obviously wouldn't be fine in a class.

Answer (score 40):

I've occasionally done "shocking" things to send an important message. It might be that all he intends is to make it a dramatic statement that you (the class) should take it more seriously.

I doubt that he intends to not return, and also doubt that he would get any administrative support for that.

I've always been willing to fail the entire class. Also willing to give full marks to the entire class. But that depends on individual, not group, behavior. Again, failing person A because of the actions of B would be unethical and would draw no administrative support.

If it is only one student then, perhaps, a more nuanced and less dramatic response would probably be called for.

In one of my "dramatic explosions" not every student was guilty. But even the ones who were more conscientious got an important message about proper behavior. In this case it was more about their own lack of preparation. There is a scene in *Stand And Deliver* in which the teacher, Jaime Escalante, denies entry to the classroom to a student who doesn't have his homework paper ready to turn in: "If you don't have a ticket, you don't get to watch the show."

But hopefully, the need for such drama is infrequent.

Comment: Maybe you can add some examples and reasons besides possible repercussions to you as a teacher if there are any? I mean the work framework of the school when things like this 'dramatic explosions' happen?

Comment: "If you don't have a ticket, you don't get to watch the show." - I would have thought the course fees were the ticket?

I get the point that if someone isn't engaged in learning, there's not much point attending class.

What I wonder is where the teacher's assumption that the only way to engage is to uncritically listen to them comes from. Maybe students are cross-referencing information online?

Actually knowing the best way for all your students to learn would require some sort of telepathy. Shouldn't modern institutions would be more attuned to diverse methods of student learning?

Comment: @Bruno I can't imagine you seriously and honestly think people on their phone during class are "cross-referencing information"…

Comment: @Bruno "I would have thought the course fees were the ticket? " - I agree, modern institutions should be more attuned to modern reality. Why not just have a sliding scale of course fees corresponding to the grade you want? $100 gets you a C, $1,000 gets you an A. No need to waste time sitting in lecture rooms, taking tests, etc! </irony>.

Comment: @Blackhole when I was in school, I would very frequently look things up during class. (not on my phone at the time, because it wasn't capable of accessing the internet in a meaningful way, but I would use it as a calculator.) Now I frequently do look things up in meetings. Phone, laptop, book, doesn't necessarily mean disengaged.

Comment: @Bruno A teacher-student relationship where the student pays the teacher for accreditation and the teacher is the servant of the student tends not to work in terms of transferring knowledge.  So you pay the institution for permission to attend and be evaluated, not the teacher for instruction and accreditation.  The "ticket" is then **doing the work to learn**, not **handing over cash**.  If you hand over cash and don't do the work to learn, you aren't fulfilling your part of the bargain.  And yes, they get to keep the cash.

Comment: Bruno and Mr.Mindor are completely right. By paying for those classes you are paying for the access, and it's up to the student to get the best she can.  Also cross referencing, or googling info is the most normal. Sometimes teachers dont explain concepts in an understandable way and searching online at the moment is the way to go to make your notes.   Also, @Yakk, do not forget that for many centuries teachers have been employees or servants, either of the wealthy or of the state.And it has worked, but self learning has always been quite effective.

Comment: @Bruno : A "modern institution" should be aware that most claims of "diverse methods of student learning" are unsupportable.  See, for instance, [this summary](https://www.psychologicalscience.org/news/releases/learning-styles-debunked-there-is-no-evidence-supporting-auditory-and-visual-learning-psychologists-say.html) or [the original article](https://www.psychologicalscience.org/journals/pspi/PSPI_9_3.pdf).

Comment: @EricTowers the criticisms of the research studies might be valid, but that doesn't mean the claims are wrong. As one of the people who has a different learning style (I assimilate almost nothing presented visually or verbally, making traditional lectures nearly worthless to attend from a learning perspective), I can say definitively that either traditional lectures are a universally terrible format for teaching (because everyone learns like me), or diverse learning methods definitely exist (because I don't learn like everyone else).

Comment: Note that "If you don't have a ticket, you don't get to watch the show." is a line from the movie. I don't know if Escalante ever actually delivered it to his students, but the history is that he was an extremely effective teacher of AP Calculus to poor an under-performing students. He did it by making them work. Hard.

Comment: You should point out that this is something that likely varies between countries, and even schools. As you probably know, in the US, academic freedom in part means we are not required to teach someone who does not meet some minimum standard, which we have some flexibility to decide. Many of the details of the standard are decided collectively by the faculty. Complete freedom to determine the grade students get, including failing the entire class, is a rather controversial topic; administrations at some schools have been known to step in and change grades, but it makes the news when they do.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm, agreed. But there are a few instances of students forming a cabal to refuse, collectively, to cooperate. But, again, you can't fail A because of the actions of B. So failing the entire class would require that each student fails independently, in some sense. My statement that I would be willing to fail everyone was (as it should be) interpreted as, if _you_ don't perform, then _you_ will fail and there is no _curve_ that will save you.

Comment: A undergrad professor of mine used a graduate student as a plant to set up a shocking incident at the start of semesters. The confedrate would be sitting on an asile about half way up the ampitheator (big class) holding the campus paper in front of their face; the professor stopped in mid sentence with eyes fixed dramatically on the paper, strolled to the base of the aisle, bounded up the steps, snatched the paper and balled it up and sent the "offender" out in disgrace. The impact was only slightly lessened when you learned that it happened every semester.

Comment: *Again, failing person A because of the actions of B would be unethical and would draw no administrative support.* - by extension, isn't is just as unethical to walk out on the students who were actually paying attention, because of the actions of those who were perceived to not be paying attention (because they were on their phones)?

Comment: @dwizum, sometimes. But sometimes a dramatic lesson is needed. A professor has a lot of ways to compensate for a short absence so that the students don't get disadvantaged. It is a judgement call that I can't make at a distance.

Comment: But who needs the dramatic lesson? And is the need for drama enough to justify creating potential issues for students who are paying attention? Since you brought up *Stand and Deliver* - imagine if Escalante had denied access to *every student* because a few hadn't brought their homework. Wouldn't that be absurd? And isn't that basically the same thing that this walk-out professor has done?

Comment: @dwizum, actually, again, it depends. But the professor needs an educational reason behind such actions. They may be warranted or not in any specific situation. Education involves more than _delivering content_ efficiently.

Comment: To be clear here, I agree that professors should have some leeway. But - speaking as a student who was generally a bigtime rule-following goodie-two-shoes - if one of my professors had walked out because some of my fellow students were using cell phones, I would have been furious. I agree that education involves more than delivering content, but it seems pretty heavy handed to walk out on *all* of your students because *a few* of them were not behaving. Certainly, there are effective ways to deal with misbehaving students that do not involve also punishing innocent bystanders.

Comment: @dwizum, "punishing" is your characterization, but not necessarily mine. Would you be furious at just the prof or at the students causing the disruption?

Comment: Both, actually. But does it matter? Because the professor was trying to make a point (apparently), the attention-paying students are now left without a lecture. But the irony is, they didn't need that point made - they were already putting in the effort to pay attention to a lecture they'd paid for, and attended. No one needed to teach them to pay attention. Surely, there's a more appropriate, and focused, way to deal with students who aren't paying attention.

Comment: @dwizum Your contract is with the school and so if the prof doesn't deliver, you beef is with the school too, since they are the ones that have the "duty" to you and owe you compensation. The faculty have a job and the right to set conditions under which they will and won't do it, which is a different contract between faculty and the school.

Answer (score 9):

> Would he be able or be allowed to not teaching, let us handle it ourselves and only come to do the test?

Depends on your university's policies, but in general no. Instructors of record have wide latitude over how they manage their classrooms, but refusing to teach for weeks at a time would almost certainly be over the line at virtually every institution.

> Would he be able to fail the whole class?

Some professors have [tried](http://www.insidehighered.com/news/2015/04/27/professor-fails-his-entire-class-and-his-university-intervenes) [this](https://nextshark.com/flamingo-kuo-taiwanese-professor-fails-his-entire-class-after-one-negative-feedback-from-a-student/) and the university generally intervenes. Certainly failing an entire class because of a few bad actors is difficult to defend. If there is a reasonable final exam and not a single student manages to pass it, then failing the entire class could be an appropriate outcome. However, this would reflect poorly on the professor's teaching skills (and/or the university's admissions policies).

> Would he possibly react the same way if only 1 student use the phone without making any noise?

You'd have to ask him. Certainly this reaction would be more difficult to justify in such a case.

Comment: Re: "reflect poorly on... the university's admissions policies". Keep in mind in the U.S. half of college students are attending community colleges, and most community colleges are open admissions -- i.e., no admissions policies.

Comment: Fair enough, though I think the "and/or" covers this :-)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a defensible action if *everyone* in the classroom were on their phones. As other answers have pointed out, professors tend to be given rather wide latitude by their institutions (especially if they're tenured), and there may arguably be some value in "shock-and-awe" style approaches like this one when used sparingly.

However, the sticking point here is this sentence, which I've modified for emphasis:

> My professor left the classroom before class ended because, like he said, **too many students** were using phones while he was talking.

"Too many" does not mean all. Therefore, what the professor did was unfair and inappropriate. If there's *one* student sitting there in the classroom who honestly wants to learn and is doing everything they can to pay attention, then the professor is obligated to perform their job out of respect for and contractual obligation to that student.

It is not the fault of the students who are *not* using cell phones that "too many" of their peers are using cell phones. There isn't anything you can reasonably expect the non-cell-phone-using students to do in order to get their cell-phone-using peers to stop—and certainly not during the class. Therefore, it is unreasonable to punish the non-cell-phone-using students for their cell-phone-using peers' actions.

Aside from that and whether or not it is permissible, I'd judge this as a major over-reaction, assuming that what you said about the lack of disruptions is true. At the university level, students are mature enough to be responsible for their own education and decisions. Instructors can and should support them, encourage them, and possibly even *cajole* them into making the correct decisions. But the students are still ultimately responsible for making and paying the price for their own decisions. Therefore, if a student wants to sit in a lecture without paying attention, that's really their prerogative. It only becomes something that the instructor needs to address if their choosing-not-to-pay-attention becomes a *distraction* for other students who are trying to pay attention. As, for example, would happen if phones were ringing or otherwise making noise. And at that point, the "dramatic gesture" would be to kick out those students who were creating a distraction, then continue the lecture for the benefit of those students who wanted to hear it.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Frankly, I'm surprised that many of the other answers seem to support the professor's actions, even if indirectly. It seems clearly and obviously unethical to ignore the students who *are* paying attention in an attempt to send a message to those the professor thinks are not paying attention.

Comment: I also upvoted - anon dvd though. It's unfair on the diligent students to walk out, as it's depriving them. The phone users won't be adversly affected, as they disengaged themselves anyhow. They are the ones who ought to be *not* in the lecture. They've vitually absented themselves anyway!

Answer (score 1):

> Would he be able or be allowed to not teach, and let us handle it ourselves and only come in to do the test?

It wouldn't come to that. He "counter-provoked" you to realize you (= the students taking the class) were crazy for not making sure that class can be given without interruption, and that it would lead to ruin. Probably and hopefully you will take the hint, individually and collectively, and next time there will be no or almost-no students busy with their phones.

> Would he possibly react the same way if only 1 student used their phone without making any noise?

No. He would either ignore it or call out that student and make him/her put their phone away.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the country and if the school is public or private. If the teacher is considered an employee and does that then he can be charged for abandoning work or breaking his contract of services with the school if the entire class goes to complain to the school administration, in which case the teacher could even be fired. BUT on the vast majority of situations... yes, he can. To answer the questions:

1-Would he be able or be allowed to not teaching, let us handle it ourselves and only come to do the test?

R- Yes. However petty and childish that is he can and would. Of course he should be reported, but best the student can do is ask another teacher of the same subject/class to allow you as listener (just to enter class and hear the lecture). Modern times do require modern solutions too, so making a scandal in social media might help. On the other hand, it could be argued that he was teaching you all a lesson.

2-Would he be able to fail the whole class?
R- Yes. He can, or fail someone he doesnt like. In which case the whole class or the affected ones can make an official petition or procedure, based on the class's plan deliverable homeworks, to be graded by an external source. That is a normal procedure in most universities.

3-Would he possibly react the same way if only 1 student use the phone without making any noise?
R- That is hard to answer without knowing the person, but petty behavior does come from petty people, so yes, he could, or he might  try to use that student as an example for everyone.

Having said that, you should consider that  its basic respect and manners to not be messing with your phone when someone is speaking to you. More so, it's a class where you are supposed to be learning, so you'd be wasting the chance.  If he did stated at the start of the course that he would not allow using phones, then the class is at fault.

However, to take into account is that there are many teacher, the older ones specially, that do not understand just how integrated is modern learning and technology. You could be taking notes on a tablet/notbook/smart-paperbook, check what he says and references on the phone, sending the photos of the whiteboard to the class's chat group, using the cloud to share the materials, etc . If that was the case, the whole group needs to speak to the teacher about it and get clear what is expected or allowed.

Comment: What would be the difference between public/private?

Comment: Public- Generally teachers are protected by syndicates/unions (which in many countries are mafias), so they can do (or do not do) almost whatever they want as long as they dont cause trouble for the leaders.
Private- There are 2 types. The for profit where the teacher would get repercussions because the alumni are clients and the objective is to get them to graduate (here there would be consequences for the teacher), or the private serious ones where the teacher can do almost anything and the school will back up the teacher to retain status.

Comment: Your language suggests you're disuccsing secondary education. This site is for tertiary.

Comment: @ Azor Ahai Language does not suggest. It speaks regardless of level where only initial ones would differ. It could be for a secondary, university level, MBA, PDH or POSTDOC. It's the same.

Comment: I don't understand what your second sentence means, or what postdocs have to do with this. But in tertiary education, we don't have "teachers" and very few lecturers/professors are unions, and certainly no one would consider university lecturer unions to be "mafias."

Comment: @AzorAhai faculty unions are relatively common in the US. They take on some of the decisions otherwise handled by the faculty senate and particular committees. I'm not quite sure what deags means by mafias but I doubt there's any point in arguing about it.

Comment: @Azor Ahai . If you read the response you'll notice the "...It depends on the country ..." , and in many countries, teacher's unions ARE legal mafias that governments use to retain a captive voting masses (just look at latinamerica) . Also,  lecturers/professors=teacher, there is no difference.

Comment: @deags It seems like English isn't your first language. *lecturers/professors=teacher, there is no difference* This just isn't correct. Those are different things (in different countries). In English-speaking universities, no is  called a "teacher" although they often do teach. I would encourage you to read up on the differences, because referring to professors as "teachers" (in English) suggests you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Azor Ahai  Once more I recommend you to read the answer, where you'll notice the **"...It depends on the country ..." **, also, you can read any english thesaurus and you'll find that 'teacher' is a perfect synonym for 'professor'. In any case, the discrepancy regarding your perception of regarding only your english experience would only restrict to a very concrete and small sample the response rather than enrich it with international context.